# Savon proxy works in script, not in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, proxy, savon

I'm using Savon to make calls to a SOAP API.  The API I'm accessing requires calls to be coming from a whitelisted IP address, so I'm using a QuotaGuard proxy.

The call that I'm making returns perfectly in IRB and also as a plain ruby script.  When I put the *exact same* code into a method in my Rails model, the call times out because it isn't coming through the proxy IP.  QuotaGuard has a dashboard where I can look at requests going through the proxy IP, so I know for sure that this call is not going through.

Here is my ruby script code:

```
require 'savon'

ping_request = Savon.client do
    wsdl "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/svbase4api/Ping?wsdl"
    proxy "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@us-east-1-static-brooks.quotaguard.com:9293"
end

response = ping_request.call(:ping, message: {message: "oogly boogly"})

puts response.to_hash[:ping_response][:return]
```

The puts statement does exactly what I want.  It puts "saved ping message oogly boogly"

Here's my Rails model:

```
class Debitcard < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.ping
    ping_request = Savon.client do
        wsdl "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/svbase4api/Ping?wsdl"
        proxy "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@us-east-1-static-brooks.quotaguard.com:9293"
    end

    response = ping_request.call(:ping, message: {message: "oogly boogly"})

    puts response.to_hash[:ping_response][:return]

    @ping_response = response.to_hash[:ping_response][:return]
  end

end
```

And this is the result in the rails server when I press a button which posts to the controller action which calls the **ping** method:

> D, [2014-10-23T18:38:08.587540 #2200] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to
>   xx.xxx.xxx.xx (net_http) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 75228ms
>
> Errno::ETIMEDOUT (Operation timed out - connect(2)):

Can anyone shine a light on this?  Thanks!

Comment: This was ultimately an issue with my installation of Savon.  After uninstalling and reinstalling the latest stable version of the Savon gem, I'm back in action!